# How to Set a Series of setHeader's DRY

Tags: javascript, node.js, dry

I'm just learning to use the [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and I can't figure how to set a series of `setHeader`'s `DRY` (if at all possible??).

Any help is appreciated.

```
function plugin(options) {
  var defaults = {
      cache:                 0
    , port:                  8080
    , host:                  'localhost'
    , verbose:               false
    , serverInfo:            'myserver'
    , cacheControl:          'no-store'
    , xPowerBy:              'Locomotion'
    , xFrameOptions:         'DENY'
    , xXSSProtection:        '1; mode=block'
    , xContentTypeOption:    'nosniff'
    , contentSecurityPolicy: 'default-src "self"'
  };

  var opts = options || {};

  setDefaults(opts, defaults);

  return function(files, staticsmith, done) {

    if (server) {
      done();
      return;
    }

    // Some stuff

    server = require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {

      response.setHeader('X-Powered-By',            opts.xPowerBy);
      response.setHeader('x-frame-options',         opts.xFrameOptions);
      response.setHeader('X-XSS-Protection',        opts.xXSSProtection);
      response.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options',  opts.xContentTypeOption);
      response.setHeader('Cache-Control',           opts.cacheControl);
      response.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', opts.contentSecurityPolicy);

    // Does some more stuff
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a major/offensive violation of the DRY principal because you are setting the header for different options/values each time.

Checking the [**documentation**](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#response.setHeader), it doesn't seem there is an overload that accepts an array of objects or objects with multiple header properties.

However, if you want to improve the code visually(and completely remove duplication), you can take a 'data-driven' approach and use an array

```
var headers = [{
    name: 'X-Powered-By',
    option: opts.xPowerBy
}, {
    name: 'x-frame-options',
    option: opts.xFrameOptions
}, {
    name: 'X-XSS-Protection',
    option: opts.xXSSProtection
}, {
    name: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
    option: opts.xContentTypeOption
}, {
    name: 'Cache-Control',
    option: opts.cacheControl
}, {
    name: 'Content-Security-Policy',
    option: opts.contentSecurityPolicy
}];
```

and then loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
    response.setHeader(headers[i].name, headers[i].option);
}
```

Comment: Thnx, i kinda figued so and I'll take a cliser look when I get back in.

Comment: @CelticParser, think about it...calling a method multiple times is a sign you are **not** repeating yourself. A true violation of the DRY principal would be, say, if you took the code in `setHeader` itself and repeated it sequentially. The problem isn't repeated *method calls*. The problem is code *itself* repeated(like code blocks, or even single lines of code that can be optimized into a loop)